# Touch not detected - subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now. I am using auto layout with a scrollview. Inside the scrollview is a UIView, another UIView and then the subview within that. I can't get touch to work with the subview. I have tried touchesbegan along with uitapgesture with no success. Any suggestions? Here is the layout hierarchy.

```
ScrollView
---- UIView
     ------- UIView
             ------ UIView - Need to detect touch here.
```

EDIT:

Sorry guys, was at work. Here is some code. I have subclassed my scrollview to receive touches as it seems to be working best so far getting down to the subview level of other view subviews.

The following code detects that the view is that class without the pointInside. I am currently having issues receiving the right point for the view.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UIView *relatedVidsView = [[[touches allObjects] firstObject] view];

for (int i = 0; i < relatedVidsView.subviews.count; i++) {
    UIView *view = [relatedVidsView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[[touches allObjects] firstObject] locationInView:self];

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[RecipeVideoView class]] && [view pointInside:touchPoint withEvent:nil]) {
        NSLog(@"TEST");
    }
}

[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; }
```

EDIT 2:

So I was able to figure this out. I subclassed the view that was containing the subviews that i needed touch events for. What I did was passed the events from the parent to the subviews using touchesBegan. I will post my code later, thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Please add code for tap gesture.

Comment: Please show me some code, may be i can help you

Comment: Did you set user interaction enable for that subview?

Comment: Try setting userInteractionEnabled = YES for the subview and all its superviews. Also please add some code

Comment: Let me get back to everyone with code, I didn't post because I have been deleting what has not been working. The only thing I got to work so far was hitTest but then say the user tries to scroll when their finger is on top of that view it will click the view and hitTest is also called multiple times.

Comment: @Arun I have tried that will no success.

Comment: Can you check your Debug View Hierarchy? I seriously doubt your subview on which tap is not recognizing is out of the frame of its super view

Comment: Yea something like this. Can you check the debug hierarchy and check whether any subview is out of the frame of your superview

Comment: I did that was helpful thanks @Arun

Comment: So your subview was out of the frame of its super view?